# restore broken cpp libs linux

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

So, I was trying to compile dlib but it spitted out many errors. Appearently, my cpp files are broken.

Even as simple as compiling a `cout << "Hello World";` with g++ resolves in issues.

Here's the log:

https://pastebin.com/bTkdaycn

Is there any way to "restore" broken cpp files? I haven't really messed around with the libraries.

Yes, I WANT TO reinstall (remove/install) CPP 11 libs. I just don't know, how. I tried apt install --reinstall and dpkg-reconfigure and everything.

Thank you in advice

Comment: Probably easiest to restore the packages from your distribution's package manager if you've broken them

Comment: If you don't know what file you broke, it's probably easier to reinstall lthe whole system.

Comment: What have you tried? Also: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2342207

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I got it.

For everyone wondering, I went to my windows pc, which had wsl on it.

I scp'd the entire /usr/include/c++/11 directory to myself and replaced. Now everything works. Like a dirty wooden-hammer solution, but it's a solution